# Pushing a string into cin from a bash script (C++ program)

Tags: c++, bash, shell

This should be a simple issue, but I have not found a conrete answer.

In a program I have written, I am getting a line from the user through:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

This is the only input I get in my program.

I need to write a bash script to test some user inputs, but I am unsure how to push a string specified in the script to my program so my program treats the string like it was entered at the command line.

The script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "running test"

//somehow direct string specified here into my program
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: `echo "running test" | ./myexecutable` - look at pipes and I/O redirection in bash, e.g https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: @orip Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)):

```
echo "some input" | ./myprogram
```

Normally when you run `./myprogram` its *standard input* is connected to the tty (terminal).

When you use a pipe in the shell, it connects your program's *standard input* to the *standard output* of the preceding program.

Since `echo` by default includes a newline character, your program will see

```
some input\n
```

followed by end-of-file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the pipeline option, you could also use a here-document:

```
./myprogram <<EOF-MARKER
some input
EOF-MARKER
```

Note that you can send multiple lines this way (everything up to the end-of-file marker string).

If you're actually using bash (not some brand-X shell), you can use a here-string (note the triple-`<` instead of double):

```
./myprogram <<<"some input"
```